# How to Pass Method Name In Variable In Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I’m not sure if it’s possible but what I’m tying to do is to pass a method name in a variable to grandchild.

On my page there is “topbar” component, which contains “button” component.

```
// Home.vue
<my-topbar :buttons="buttons"></my-topbar>

data() {
  return {
    buttons: [
      {
        type: "icon",
        icon: "delete",
        label: "delete",
        method: "deleteSelections",
      },
      {
        type: "icon",
        icon: "upload",
        label: "upload",
        method: "saveToDatabase",
      }
    ]
  };
},


// Topbar.vue
<my-button v-for="(button, index) in buttons" :key="index" :button="button"></my-button>

// Button.vue
<v-btn @click="button.method">
    <v-icon v-if="button.type !== 'text'">{{icons[button.icon]}}</v-icon>
    <span v-if="button.type !== 'icon'">{{$t(`buttons[${button.label}]`)}}</span>
</v-btn>
```

My problem is @click=“button.method” part. When I click it, it returns: “TypeError: _vm.button.method is not a function”

I tried these 2 syntax but couldn’t get any result, not even an error in this case:

```
:on-click="${button.method}"

@click="${button.method}"
```

I appreciate that if someone can tell me the correct way of doing this.
Thanks.

Comment: Clarification: The methods ("saveToDatabase", "deleteSelection") are methods of `my-button`, correct?

Comment: @Tanner Yes, those methods are in the Button.vue file. They will trigger some other methods in Home.vue via event bus (I guess.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSB Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-4bdn0)

Forgive the lack of styling, and I can't figure out why the text isn't showing up on the button. But - here's what I did.

Pass the `buttons` array to the header, as you're doing now. in `Button.vue` add a `@click` handler to call a proxy method `callMethod(button.method)`. The important part is this proxy method:

```
 methods: {
    saveToDatabase() {
      console.log("Save to database!");
    },
    deleteSelections() {
      console.log("Delete seleciton!");
    },
    callMethod(method) {
      this[method]();
    }
```

The `callMethod` in its entirety is `this[method]()`. As long as the method passed in exists in the component's methods, it will call it. `this` in this case refers to the component. The brackets will call the evaluated value of whatever's passed in. Here's an explanation on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173791/7375929